# VB.Net Program Not Saving to database after publish

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

So i have published my program to the clients PC and first i have a login form that works perfectly, but for some reason when i try to save or update or delete the database it doesn't save or delete the information i have try catch errors in all my save and delete buttons with a msgbox "Entry Failed" and that keeps showing up, how to i fix this error btw my database is MS Access

Comment: you didnt install it on your machine like a user would to test it first?

Comment: could the database be readonly when installed?

Comment: yes i did and it was working

Comment: i'll check the read only

Comment: its set to read only that seems to be the problem, but im trying to remove it

Answer (score 0):

ok i fixed it my problem was that i put the program folder in C:\Program Files which had its folder properties set to read only so i moved it to documents and it works fine